# Embedding video for all browsers (including Mac Firefox!)

Tags: macos, firefox, video

I've seen a bunch of threads around referencing various video embedding issues. Unfortunately I'm not in a position to serve my assets off of a CDN (or Youtube, Vimeo, etc) so have resorted to working with multiple formats. I've got .mp4, .ogg, and .swf.

I'm continuing to get an error in Firefox (Mac) regarding "no video of the requested MIME type can be found." I've added mp4 and ogg to my .htaccess file to no avail.

Which makes me think there must be something slightly wrong with my code. I've used a combination of the suggested methods I've found online. I'm hoping I've done something so obviously daft that it will stick out like a sore thumb to someone in the know.

```
<video width="757" height="425" controls id="player">

  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="video.ogg" type="video/ogg">

  <object classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab" width="757" height="425" >
    <param name="src" value="video.mp4">
    <param name="controller" value="true">

    <embed SRC="QTMimeType.pntg" type="image/x-macpaint" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download" qtsrc="video.swf" 
    width="757" height="425" autoplay="false" controller="true">
    </embed>    
  </object> 

</video>
```

Many thanks in advance for taking a look at this. Feeling pretty stupid right now.

Comment: Apart from their extensions, did you verified that the file you have on your server are of the correct mimetype? E.g. .mp4 is `video/mp4`, etc...

Comment: I ssh'd to my host to check mime-types.
The MP4 had no mime-type.
The OGG had "application/octet-stream".
The SWF had "application/x-shockwave-flash".

The main problem is probably the lack of mime-type on the MP4. I've had the videos provided to me - is this an issue at the export stage, or something on my server?

Comment: I think it's an issue with your WS that should assign the MIME type `video/mp4` to .mp4 and so on

Comment: This is the first line of my .htaccess file, in the root of my WS.
"AddType video/mp4 mp4 m4v"

Comment: Can you try with another web server?